# Node js Winston: stop writing "message" field

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, logging, winston

I'm using Winston library for logging some data to .log file in JSON with winston.transports.File transport. When any data is logged, the library attaches fields "level", "timestamp" and "message" to it. In fact, I need only 2 first fields and really don't want logger to add the third one. How can I do this?

Comment: You can create your own custom logger that logs anything you'd like, read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. Is it the only choice?